# replace "." with space using gsub() in R?

Tags: r, gsub

I have data as below, I like to replace "." with space using gsub() but I could not get correct output.

```
data<-c("12.57869486" ,"12.57869582" ,"12.57870155")

a<- gsub("."," ", data)
a
[1] "           " "           " "           "
```

Comment: Or try escaping the dot: `gsub("\\.", " ", data)`

Comment: or use `chartr(".", " ", data)`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Many way to achieve this:

1) Use the `fixed` parameter of gsub:

From `?gsub`:

> fixed  logical. If TRUE, pattern is a string to be matched as is.
>   Overrides all conflicting arguments.

So adding `fixed=TRUE` to your command is enough to avoid intepreting the . as any character (regex mode):

```
> a<-gsub(".", " ", data, fixed=TRUE)
> a
[1] "12 57869486" "12 57869582" "12 57870155"
```

2) Use `chartr` (from G. Grothendieck comment):

```
chartr(".", " ", data)
```

3) Escape the special char `.` which mean any character in regex: (from Tim Biegeleisen comment)

- `gsub("\\.", " ", data)` Escape with a double backslash
- `gsub("[.]", " ", data)` Escape using character class

In long regex I tend to prefer the second syntax as I find it more readable.